# Como hago para que haya un minimo espacio entre cada imagen?

Tags: html, css

Cuando le pongo display: inline-block; las imagenes muestran un elevado espacio entre ellas, y solo quiero que se el minimo

```css
   .creditos{ 
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;}
```

```html
 <div > 
        <img class="creditos" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=1x&id=2969&format=png" alt="Facebook">
        <img class="creditos" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=1x&id=2969&format=png" alt="Instagram">
        <img class="creditos" src="https://img.icons8.com/?size=1x&id=2969&format=png" alt="Correo">
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo quita los `margin`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tú mismo le estás poniendo márgenes relativos super grandes.

Si le quitas los márgenes, las muestra con un espacio mínimo:

```css
.creditos{ 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
}

.contenedor-iconos {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-iconos"> 
  <img class="creditos" src="https://i.imgur.com/Qy4XeHYs.png" alt="Facebook">
  <img class="creditos" src="https://i.imgur.com/OWdUupIs.png" alt="Instagram">
  <img class="creditos" src="https://i.imgur.com/Hb3Y1yJ.png" alt="Correo">
</div>
```

He puesto el contenedor en amarillo para que sea fácil visualizar los espacios.
Puedes probarlo aquí mismo en la respuesta haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.